# Array not creating what I want

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array being created based on a sub set of information. The first bit is about the custom columns. We get a model object back, which is an array.

So I told the method, that I am having issues with, that I want the fields to be as such:

```
    $customReportObject = array(
        'date_created' => 'project_date',
        'project_number' => 'project_number',
        'name'  => 'project_name',
        'description' => 'project_description',
        'manager' => 'project_manager_name'
    );
```

The array is set up as `custom_column_name=>actual_model_column_name`

There are two models being passed in:

```
array(
    'projects' => $activeProjects,
    'PM' => $projectManager
)
```

The array is set up as `model_name=>model`, the model is an array of arrays.

So then we pass the following into:

```
private function customCollumns($model, $fields){
    $result = array();

    foreach($model as $modelName=>$modelObject){
        foreach($modelObject as $model){
            foreach($fields as $fieldName=>$actualName){
                if(array_key_exists($actualName, $model)){
                    $result[$fieldName] = $model[$actualName];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
 }
```

Which returns me an array that, when `var_dump`ed looks like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["date_created"]=>
  string(10) "1381903200"
  ["project_number"]=>
  string(5) "02785"
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "gfhfghfgh"
  ["description"]=>
  string(9) "fghgfhfgh"
  ["manager"]=>
  string(11) "Kevin Allen"
}
```

Now this is what I wanted but its not. One, there are 266 of this, like there should be. **ACCEPT!** all 266 are the exact same **MINUS** the `manager` that always changes. I am positive there is something wrong with my loops and how it creates the result array. The `$activeProjects` when `var_dump`ed consists of 266 DIFFERENT arrays, by different I mean all content of each array is different.

Can some one tell me why I am getting back 266 of the same thing minus the manager and how I would fix that?

Comment: You appear to be repeatedly reassigning the same `$result[$fieldName]`, over and over for each model.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just repeatedly filling in the same elements of the `$result` array. You want a 2-dimensional array, so you need to create a sub-array for each model, and append that to the main result array.

```
private function customCollumns($model, $fields){
    $result = array();

    foreach($model as $modelName=>$modelObject){
        foreach($modelObject as $i => $model){
            $new_array = isset($result[$i]) ? $result[$i] : array();
            foreach($fields as $fieldName=>$actualName){
                if(array_key_exists($actualName, $model)){
                    $new_array[$fieldName] = $model[$actualName];
                }
            }
            $result[$i] = $new_array;
        }
    }

    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: While this works, were missing the `manager` from the array. in fact you skip the manager model all together, and thus its never added because it's key `project_manager_name` is never found. ideas? There are two models being passed in to create on uniform custom "array"

Comment: I've changed the answer so that for each model, it updates the same elements in `$result` instead of creating new elements. I hope I understand your data structures correctly.

Comment: So your first array in the massive array of arrays gave me a manager, yay - but they should all have a manager and they dont. just the first one